# How to set the default size selector to be unselected?

Tags: shopify

I'm looking to default my size variant selector to not select anything. Currently, it's selecting the smallest variant size. I want to change it so none of the variants are selected to start out with. [Here's a perfect example on Urban Outfitters](https://www.urbanoutfitters.com/shop/project-social-t-modern-fit-tee?category=latest-mens-fashion&color=041&type=REGULAR) of how I want it to look. [Shopify describes how to remove it from every theme but Brooklyn (which is what I'm using)](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/products/variants/how-to-add-a-pick-an-option-to-drop-downs), but I'm thinking this would an easy fix to just have it not selected on anything. Here's my code.

```
<select name="id" id="ProductSelect" class="product-single__variants 
no-js">
{% for variant in product.variants %}
{% if variant.available %}
<option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant 
%}
selected="selected" {% endif %}
data-sku="{{ variant.sku }}"
value="{{ variant.id }}">
{{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}
</option>
{% else %}
<option disabled="disabled">
{{ variant.title }} - {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
</option>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Button style selector just add the following code at the end of **theme.js.liquid**

This will reset the checkbox selection.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.product-form__item input[type=radio]').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: You're awesome. You don't know how long I've been trying to figure this out for. Thanks so much dude, I really appreciate it.